# Migration-Manager / binary compatibility: overriding hash-code with reference to private[this]

Tags: scala, binary-compatibility, migration-manager

Why is overriding `hashCode` a binary incompatible change:

Before:

```
trait Foo extends Product
```

After:

```
trait Foo extends Product {
  private[this] lazy val _hashCode = ScalaRunTime._hashCode(this)
  override def hashCode: Int = _hashCode
}
```

Migration-Manager says:

```
[error]  * synthetic method Foo$$_hashCode()Int in trait Foo is present only in current version
[error]    filter with: ProblemFilters.exclude[ReversedMissingMethodProblem]("Foo.Foo$$_hashCode")
```

Is this actually a problem? Or can I stay on the same minor version with this change?

Comment: What version of MiMa are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but it's possibly to avoid the `private[this] lazy val` altogether:

```
trait Foo extends Product {
  override lazy val hashCode: Int = ScalaRunTime._hashCode(this)
}
```

Here, MiMa does not complain.